# How can I use regex to find the following pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings like so:

```
["Author Name, (p. 123). (2019). Company.", "Author Name, (p. 321). (2021). Company."]
```

How can I return the page numbers that start with and contain the pattern `(p.`?

So far I have tried `/\(([^)\)]+)\)/` however it returns everything with parentheses. I only want the page numbers with parentheses.

Comment: if you are looking for a p why dont you have a p in your pattern?

Comment: Maybe including the text you know exists would help?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'm pretty new to regex. I did try adding a [p] where the '^' is however I get an error as I'm unfamiliar with the format.

Comment: I'd suggest spending some time on any of several regex tutorial sites--they're *very* useful to know in general.

Comment: I would probably use this, if I understand the question correct `\(p\.\s(\d+)\)`.  I like pages like this that visualize the pattern: https://regexper.com/#%5C%28p%5C.%5Cs%28%5Cd%2B%29%5C%29

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I'll be reading up more on this as it's pretty fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the `p.` before the capture group and capture the numbers. You don't have to escape the parenthesis in the character class, so you can remove `\)` and leave just `)`

```
\(p\.\s*([^)]+)\)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BeYtJ9/1).

```js
const regex = /\(p\.\s*([^)]+)\)/g;
[
  "Author Name, (p. 123). (2019). Company.",
  "Author Name, (p. 321). (2021). Company."
].forEach(s => {
  Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => console.log(m[1]))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd capture digits (you need `(p.s.)`?), case-insensitive (what about `(P.12)`?):

```js
/\(p\.\s*(\d+)\)/ig
```

**Code**

```js
const regex = /\(p\.\s*(\d+)\)/gi
const string = "Author Name, (p. 123). (2019). Company."
console.log(string.match(regex).map(x => x.replace(/\D+/g, '')))
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/5A5QPP/1).